# How can I disable encrypted data in SSMS to be visible to whoever has access to the database?

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, ssms

I have a table with an encrypted column. The table looks like this:

```
------------------------------
| id (pk) | name (encrypted) |
------------------------------
| 1       | tom              |
| 2       | john             |
| 3       | fred             |
------------------------------
```

Within SSMS using the wizard I encrypted the name column, and this works.
I even created an application which correctly displays all data (using 'column encryption setting = enabled').

The issue is the following: When I change the setting 'column encryption setting' to be enabled, I can see the data in SSMS. This isnt supposed to happen, since people who have access to the database should not be able to see this column.

How can I make this column only ever readable in an application?

This is the encryption code:

```
ENCRYPTED WITH (COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = [CEK_Auto1], ENCRYPTION_TYPE = Deterministic, ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256') NULL, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: If you don't want people to be able to view a column, why not give them an explicit `DENY` on the column? If you encrypted the column, show us the SQL you used to encrypt it, and the SQL you're using to query it so that we can replicate your problem.

Comment: added encryption code